# How to build a new field with an if condition in Python through Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a field that will assign values based on if column a = column b, column c (The new field) will equal no, if not, then yes. Exactly same as an excel formula =IF(A2=B2,"No", "Yes"). I'm using .loc on the data source and equal the name of the fields and it is printing Yes for all fields. Is there a better way to do this, or should I just try to correct this code?

Code below:

```
Df.loc[df['Field 1'] == 'Field 2', 'New Field'] = 'No'


Df.loc[df['Field 1'] != 'Field 2', 'New Field'] = 'Yes'
```

Comment: Use numpy.where: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where

Comment: Thanks Mr Fooz. Can you specifically write out the code utilizing np.where? Tried it a few times but keep getting different errors. The code I posted at least gets creates the new field and gets me something.

Comment: I got it to create the field with np.where, but it gives me the same issue where it us printing out yes for each cell under the new field. I played around with it and replace "Field 2" with a value under Field 1. So for example, if 10, print no in the new field. So it works well when you specify something in the field, but is there any way to do it for each field individually? Ex. row 3 of field 1 = row 3 of field 2, then row 3 of new field is no. This is what I want. Any way to do this?

Comment: Seems like you are using Pandas then since you mention "I'm using .loc on the data source"? No where do you mention Pandas in your post or tags. You'd get better traction if you specify better in your title, post, and/or tags. Something like "How to build a new field with an if condition using Pandas". You'd have a better chance if you search with the correct terms you'll find the answer yourself, too. Plus a little toy code with a minimal reproducible example of a starting point and what you need to make would go a long way. See [guide here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you, Wayne. I have added Pandas. I have checked many posts and could not find the answer as none of them are doing the same thing. Do you happen to know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The result is `Yes` because  You compare the value of the first column to the string `"Field 2"` rather then the second column values. here is how you can correct it :

```
df.loc[df['Field 1'] == df['Field 2'], 'New Field'] = 'Yes'

df.loc[df['Field 1'] != df['Field 2'], 'New Field'] = 'No'
```

You do not need to use two conditions , you could initialize the value of the new column to `No`(or `Yes`) then update only the rows that met the condition using `df.loc`, here is updated version :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Field 1': [1, 2, 3], 'Field 2': [1, 4,3]}
)

df['New Field'] = 'No'


cond =  df['Field 1'] == df['Field 2']
df.loc[cond, 'New Field'] = 'Yes'


df
```

Output :

| Field 1 | Field 2 | New Field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Yes |
| 2 | 4 | No |
| 3 | 3 | Yes |

Comment: Thank you Hamza. It still didn't work and prints yes for every field.

Comment: in the example , the second row give `No`.  what data you are using ? 
could you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)